# how to add Custom CSS for Kendo Tree View nodes?

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

i'm using kendo tree view with my own data source. from there i want to add custom css class for some nodes.

Let's say I want to add a red background to some tree nodes, in a dynamically loaded Kendo UI TreeView. How can I do this?

[My expectation sample image is given below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsVml.jpg)

Comment: share your code what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

To apply CSS class dynamically to the kendo tree view nodes I have found solution using jquery. 
Inside the data source we can define **level** of the Node and according to the level we can add CSS class inside the Kendo tree view Data bound event.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/dragdrop">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.flat.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.flat.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="example">
            <div class="demo-section k-content">
                <h4>Treeview One</h4>
                <div id="treeview-left"></div>
                <h4 style="padding-top: 2em;">Treeview Two</h4>
                <div id="treeview-right"></div>
            </div>

            <script>
                

                $("#treeview-right").kendoTreeView({
                    dragAndDrop: true,
                    dataSource: [
                        { text: "Storage", Level: "first", expanded: true, items: [
                            { text: "Wall Shelving",Level: "second",items:[{text:"hi",Level: "third",}] },
                            { text: "Floor Shelving",Level: "second" },
                            { text: "Kids Storage",Level: "second" }
                        ]
                        },
                        { text: "Lights",Level: "first", items: [
                            { text: "Ceiling",Level: "second" },
                            { text: "Table",Level: "second" },
                            { text: "Floor",Level: "second" }
                        ]
                        },{ text: "fight",Level: "first", items: [
                            { text: "Ceiling",Level: "second" },
                            { text: "Table",Level: "second" },
                            { text: "Floor",Level: "second" }
                        ]
                        }
                    ],
                   dataBound:function(e){
                    
                     var treeview = $("#treeview-right").data("kendoTreeView");
                     $('#treeview-right ul li').each(function(i)
                      {
                       debugger;
                        var dataItem = treeview.dataItem(this);
                       if(dataItem.Level == "first"){
                         $(this).addClass("first");
                       }
                       if(dataItem.Level == "second"){
                         $(this).addClass("second");
                       }
                       if(dataItem.Level == "third"){
                         $(this).addClass("third");
                       }

                      });
                     

                   }
                 
                });
            </script>

            <style>
                #treeview-left,
                #treeview-right
                {
                    overflow: visible;
                }
              .first{ color:red }
              .second{ color:green }
              .third{ color:blue }
            </style>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Today I solved this for myself using kendo templates.  The code snippet below is simple, but if you want to include JavaScript logic in your rendering, then see Telerik's demo: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/templates.

My JavaScript data looks like:

```
[
    { title: 'Label', extraClasses: 'st-assembly' }
]
```

I initialize my treeview as follows:

```
 $('#structure-tree').kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: PrimaryStructure,
    dataTextField: 'title',
    template: '<span class="#: item.extraClasses #">#: item.title #</span>',
    select: onKendoTreeViewSelect,
    dragAndDrop: true,
 });
```

Before the template, the treeview element is rendered as:

```
<span class="k-in">Label</span>
```

Now the element is rendered as:

```
<span class="k-in"><span class="st-assembly">Label</span></span>
```

Hope this helps.